# ms sql server string compare to another string with multiple value

Tags: sql-server, string, compare

MS SQL Server Input Column 1 Cat 1 contains multiple values separated by a blank, Cat2 contains the value to be compared. Desired output column should be 1 if Cat2 value matches to any one of the values in Cat1 and 0 if it doesn't. Delimiter is a space. Something like -- answer = 1 if Cat1=In (cat2) after replacing blanks with comma but I don't understand the syntax to accomplish this. Could anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Cat1 VARCHAR(50),Cat2 VARCHAR(50), answer VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('3 4 6 36 a b','36','1'),
('5 4 6 36 a b','3','0'),
('7 5 6 46 a b','4','0'),
('7 5 6 46 a b','5','1'),
('3 4 6 36 a b','7','0')
select cat1, cat2 , answer
FROM @TABLE
```

go

```
Cat1                        Cat2             output
3 4 6 36 a b                 36                 1
3 4 6 36 a b                 3                  1 
3 4 6 36 a b                 4                  1
3 4 6 36 a b                 7                  0
```

Dev

Comment: Sorry - formatting of table got messed up.

Comment: The sample data is missing a test case for Cat1 = "8 4 6 36 a b", Cat2 = "3", and OUTPUT = "0". Solutions should not allow a case of just "3"   matching the "3" in the "36" which is not a valid match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c4e4/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_Table(Cat1 VARCHAR(50),Cat2 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO Test_Table VALUES
('3 4 6 36 a b','36'),
('3 4 6 36 a b','3'),
('3 4 6 36 a b','4'),
('3 4 6 36 a b','7'),
('8 4 6 36 a b','b')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN  Cat1  LIKE '% '+ Cat2
            OR    Cat1  LIKE '% '+ Cat2+ ' %'
            OR    Cat1  LIKE       Cat2+ ' %'
              THEN 1
         ELSE 0 
       END AS [OUTPUT]
FROM Test_Table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c4e4/2/0)**:

```
|         CAT1 | CAT2 | OUTPUT |
|--------------|------|--------|
| 3 4 6 36 a b |   36 |      1 |
| 3 4 6 36 a b |    3 |      1 |
| 3 4 6 36 a b |    4 |      1 |
| 3 4 6 36 a b |    7 |      0 |
| 8 4 6 36 a b |    b |      1 |
```

Comment: This solution won't actually work until you add the space-delimiter into the '%' on each of the 3 LIKE conditions. The first condition being '% ' + Cat2, the last condition being Cat2 + ' %', and the middle condition including both of those changes.  Without this the test case of just "3" will match the "3" in the "36" but that is not a valid match. The sample data is missing a test case for Cat1 = "8 4 6 36 a b", Cat2 = "3", and OUTPUT = "0".

Comment: Thank you so much srutzky for being able to correctly identify the issue even though it was poorly explained (by me) , to incognito for turning it into a table and M. ali for answering it. You're the best!

Comment: yes - indeed it was missing several test cases that I added in